# Why do I get this result using GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql

I would like a list of my states and the times when my device was last in this state.

So, if I take a short look in my db using this query:

```
SELECT state, time_start, time_end
FROM report_log
WHERE device_id = 5
ORDER BY time_end DESC
```

the result is:

```
state | time_start            | time_end
---------------------------------------------------
1     |  2019-04-12 10:47:09  |  2019-04-12 11:30:10
4     |  2019-04-12 10:45:09  |  2019-04-12 10:46:09
5     |  2019-04-11 09:37:49  |  2019-04-12 10:46:09
1     |  2019-04-12 08:37:07  |  2019-04-12 10:44:09
5     |  2019-04-11 09:37:49  |  2019-04-12 09:51:08
5     |  2019-04-11 09:37:49  |  2019-04-12 08:58:08
4     |  2019-04-12 08:33:07  |  2019-04-12 08:34:07
4     |  2019-04-12 08:33:07  |  2019-04-12 08:34:07
...
...
```

Next I want to GROUP so:

```
SELECT state, time_start, time_end
FROM (
    SELECT state, time_start, time_end
    FROM report_log
    WHERE device_id = 5
    ORDER BY time_end DESC
) AS d
GROUP BY d.state
```

but the result is:

```
state | time_start            | time_end
---------------------------------------------------
1     |  2019-04-12 11:40:10  |  2019-04-12 11:44:10
2     |  2019-04-11 05:01:45  |  2019-04-11 10:00:49
4     |  2019-04-10 12:41:32  |  2019-04-10 14:00:33
5     |  2019-04-09 06:56:07  |  2019-04-09 06:57:07
```

Why?

In the first result I can see last moment my device had state 4 was at
2019-04-12 10:46:09?

Comment: You're not using [aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html) for the dates. You also don't need to wrap the first query in a second query to group by state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `max` and `group by`

```
SELECT state, max(time_start), max(time_end)
FROM report_log
WHERE device_id = 5
GROUP BY d.state
ORDER BY time_end DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

use aggregation with group by

```
SELECT state, MIN(time_start), MAX(time_end)
FROM report_log
WHERE device_id = 5
GROUP B state
```